# How to remove an accidentally dropped file shortcut icon from Finder toolbar?

Tags: macos, finder

I accidentally dropped a file in the Finder toolbar instead of the destination folder (the ZIP icon on the right of the screenshot):
[image: OSX Lion - Finder Toolbar - Dropped File]

How can I remove it from the toolbar?

Comment: I would like to alert any new answerers to not confuse the **sidebar** with the **toolbar**. Also, be sure you are answering a Lion specific question as things can change if you have older or newer OS.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- Hold down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>
- Click file and drag it out

Comment: Is this a known OSX idiom, or just an ad-hoc command? (and if so then how did you find out about it?)

Comment: The command key has always been the modifier to use when rearranging toolbar items. It works for any toolbar, not just in Finder. You can both rearrange items and drag them out.

Comment: I tired it on my mac and its not working :( I Still can't get those stupid images off of my toolbar

Comment: If command-dragging doesn't work, you can try right-clicking and choosing "Customize Toolbar".

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. This problem I am facing from long time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's different on older versions of the OS, but I'm running OS X Lion, and I have to hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> and then drag it off.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a bunch of my files, until I realized that like all toolbars, there's a default set. Here's how to restore it:

<kbd>Control</kbd>-click (right-click) the menu bar and click Customize Toolbar...

[image]

In the sheet that presents itself, drag the default menu bar on top of your "messy" one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, too.  Right click, select "customize toolbar," THEN just drag the folder out of the toolbar.  No need to hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Comment: While true, I think the Cmd key version is easier and faster to do...

Comment: As evidenced by the many answers explaining several modifiers to be used, it's clear that for some - the customize toolbar is more friendly to some users of OS X - less likely to use a unfamiliar key therefore more likely to succeed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to hold down <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> and *then* drag the file off the toolbar.

Comment: Why 'Fn'? Should work without it as well...

Comment: No *Fn* necessary!